# Oracle Import Data dump: tablespace: "USERS" already exist

Tags: oracle, datapump, impdp

I am trying to import data using `impdp` in oracle. However, when I tried to import it, it is giving me the following error:

```
ORA-29349: tablespace "USERS" already exists
```

Since `USERS` is the defualt permenant tablespace that contains users objects, I tried to exclude it from the command by adding
"`exclude=tablespace:\" IN ('USERS')\"`"

However, adding that does not help at all as the error remains.

my command looks like following: `"impdp SYSTEM/MYPASSWORD@orcl full=Y DIRECTORY=dir dumpfile=mydump.dmp LOGFILE=mydump.dmp.log exclude=tablespace:\" IN ('USERS')\" transport_datafiles='/path/to/file"`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This error can be ignored. USERS doesn't need to be created (it already exists), but this won't prevent any other objects in your import from being created in USERS.

Comment: @pmdba i tried to use ''ignore=y'', and it says to replace with ''table_exists_action=append'', but since I am dealing with tablespace, but not table, I don't think that's what I want

Comment: I meant that you should be able to literally ignore the error. You won't be able to get rid of it, but it has no meaning in your situation; it is expected.

Comment: @pmdba this is the last message I got in the session before the message `Job SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01 stopped due to fatal error`, are you saying that they are not related?

Comment: Are you trying to do a full transportable export/import? Maybe you could just export the tablespaces you want instead of doing a full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, from what I can tell this isn't just a normal "can't create tablespace" error. This error is specific to using *transportable* tablespaces. In this case you won't be able to ignore. The work around is to *rename the existing tablespace*:

```
alter tablespace users rename to users_ts;
```

Then run your import again so that impdp can "create" the USERS tablespace from the dumpfile.

```
impdp SYSTEM/MYPASSWORD@orcl full=Y DIRECTORY=dir dumpfile=mydump.dmp LOGFILE=mydump.dmp.log transport_datafiles='/path/to/file'
```

Comment: Should I delete the original USERS when I import the new USERS? Will it cause problems

Comment: If there's nothing else in it you could drop it, or move its contents into the new USERS tablespace and then drop it.